# How to change PopUpMenu style on Android (background color)

Tags: android, layout

I'm setting a style on the menu like this:

```
Context wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(MyActivity.this, R.style.AddEffectsStyle);
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(wrapper, binding.btnAddEffect);
```

and here's how I'm doing the style

```
<style name="AddEffectsStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:itemBackground">@android:color/holo_purple</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorSecondary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/holo_purple</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

(ps: colorSecondary is green)

Here's how the PopUpMenu renders:

[image]
[image]

You can see that there's a white bar on the first image, and on the second, the background of the submenu title is white. I don't know how to change this white color.

Comment: Try changing `android:windowBackground` or `windowBackgroundFloating` attribute in your style.

Comment: @Nicolas `android:windowBackground` made no difference and there's no `android:windowBackgroundFloating`

Comment: I think it's just `windowBackgroundFloating`, no android prefix.